# Jquery how to create an array with the IDs of rows?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I get the IDs of table rows in a array?

Example I want to have:

```
var rows = // IDs of rows
```

Here is my table code:
http://pastie.org/2675460

*from paste bin:*

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="admintabel" style="width:980px;">
  <tbody><tr style="height: 40px; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bolder; font-family: Arial; cursor: move;">
    <th style="border-left:1px solid #CCCCCC">Navn</th>
    <th>Udbyder</th>
    <th>Kliks</th>
    <th>Pris md.</th>
    <th>Mindstepris</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th style="border-right:1px solid #CCCCCC"></th>
  </tr>

  <tr id="2" style="cursor: move;" class="">
    <td style="border-left:1px solid #CCCCCC">Der</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td> kr.</td>
    <td> kr.</td>
    <td><a class="viewlink" href="/bredbands/2"></a></td>
    <td><a class="editlink" href="/bredbands/2/edit"></a></td>
    <td style="border-right:1px solid #CCCCCC"><a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" data-confirm="Are you sure?" class="deletelink" href="/bredbands/2"></a></td>
  </tr><tr id="1" style="cursor: move;">
    <td style="border-left:1px solid #CCCCCC">Te</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>147 kr.</td>
    <td>148 kr.</td>
    <td><a class="viewlink" href="/bredbands/1"></a></td>
    <td><a class="editlink" href="/bredbands/1/edit"></a></td>
    <td style="border-right:1px solid #CCCCCC"><a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" data-confirm="Are you sure?" class="deletelink" href="/bredbands/1"></a></td>
  </tr>

</tbody></table>
```

If using my table the array would be [2, 1]

Comment: After 272 questions you really need to post your relevant code in your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd use `map()` and `get()`.

```
var ids = $('table tr[id]').map(function() { return this.id; }).get();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C8Dpj/).

Comment: @JamesAllardice: jQuery's `map()` will return a jQuery object.

Comment: Yeah, sorry already deleted that comment! It's too early in the morning...!

Comment: How do I change the array a bit so that the parameters in firebug would be: BREDBANDS[id] 2
BREDBANDS[id] 1 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var tr = $.makeArray($("#admintabel tr[id]")),
    rows= $.map(tr, function(item) {
        return item.id;
    });
```

it will return `["2", "1"]`;

But an ID may not start with a number value only.

if you want it as a number in the array just change the `return item.id;` to `return parseInt(item.id);`